# Attempt to get size of vector causes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to implement a `Heap` datatype, and I've hit a wall.

Since a lot of previous answers ask for moar code, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> void display_array(vector<T> arr, bool endline = true)
{
    cout << arr.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    cout << arr[arr.size() - 1];
    if(endline) cout << endl;
}

template <class T> class Heap
{
    //typedef T Node;
//    setw(...);
//private:

public:
    vector<T>* elems;
    Heap() : elems(nullptr)
    {
        this->elems = new vector<T>;
    }

    Heap(vector<T> e)
    {
        this->elems = new vector<T>(e);
    }

    Heap(vector<T>* e)
    {
        this->elems = e;
    }

    Heap(Heap<T>& h)
    {
        this->elems = new vector<T>(h.elems);
    }

    ~Heap()
    {
        delete elems;
    }

    T elemAt (int index)
    {
        return (*(this->getElems())) [index];
    }

    vector<T>* getElems()
    {
        return this->elems;
    }

    int parent (int index)
    {
        return index / 2;
    }

    long getSize()
    {
        return this->getElems()->size();
    }

    int left (int index)
    {
        return 2 * index;
    }
    T leftElem (int index)
    {
        return this->elems [2 * index];
    }

    int right (int index)
    {
        return 1 + 2 * index;
    }
    T rightElem (int index)
    {
        return this->elems [1 + 2 * index];
    }

    bool withinHeap (int index)
    {
        return index <= (this->getSize());
    }

    void maxHeapify(int index)
    {
        int largest = index;
        int l = left(index);
        int r = right(index);

        if (withinHeap(l) && elemAt(l) > elemAt(index))
        {
            if (withinHeap(r) && elemAt(r) > elemAt(l))
            {
                largest = r;
            }
            largest = l;
        }

        if (largest != index)
        {
            int temp = elemAt(index);
            elemAt(index) = elemAt(largest);
            elemAt(largest) = temp;
            delete temp;
        }
        /* or return withinHeap(l) && elemAt(l) > elemAt(index) ? withinHeap(r) && elemAt(r) > elemAt(l) ? r : l : index; :) */
    }

    void display(int current, int indent)
    {
        if(withinHeap(left(current))) display(left(current), indent + 4);
        if (indent > 0) cout << setw(indent) << " ";
        cout << elemAt(current) << endl;
        if(withinHeap(right(current))) display(right(current), indent + 4);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec {2, 5, 4, 12, 3, 9};
    Heap<int>* h = new Heap<int>(vec);
    display_array(*h->getElems());

    h->display(0, 0);


    return 0;
}
```

The last statement (`h->display(0,0)`) causes a segfault. I've narrowed it down to the `getSize()` function.

In gdb, `print this.elems` and `print *this.elems` are okay (they return object traces or whatever they're called) , but when I type `print *this.elems->size()` gdb replies with

> `Cannot access memory at address 0xbf7fffef`

I'm really new to C++ and gdb and everything. What's wrong here?

Comment: FYI, your `Heap` class can be broken with a 3 line main() program.  All due to the lack of a user-defined assignment operator..

Comment: You really don't need/want a pointer to a `vector`.

Comment: The problem isn't with your getSize() function, it's within your algorithm. I put a cout statement inside getSize() and my terminal was spammed. My guess is that you are getting a Stack Overflow due a flaw in your recursive function.

Comment: Your code looks more like Java and C# than C++. Why are you doing that new Heap<T> there? Can't you create the object directly? You should delete Heap after using it if you allocate dynamic memory for it. C++ has no garbage collector.

Comment: You should also learn to pass objects by reference, not by value.  It does look like a Java programmer's attempt at C++, which never winds up working if said programmer is using Java as a model in writing C++ code.  `Heap<int>* h = new Heap<int>(vec);`  That is the dead giveaway.  There is no need to use `new` to create that object.

Comment: @GermánDiago which Heap<T> are you talking about?

Comment: Heap<int> * in main.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury - There are many basic errors in your coding.  To fix this code would require a rewrite.  You have memory leaks, you didn't follow the "rule of 3" in the `Heap` class, you're passing by value when you should pass by (const) reference, etc...

Comment: I'm rewriting it currently to use `vector<T>` instead of a pointer. 
Can you point me to one of the memory leaks, please?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury You have a leak right in the main() function.  I can also create one by doing a simple assignment of one `Heap` object to another. `Heap h1; Heap h2; h2 = h1;`  Not only does it leak, it will call `delete` twice on the same pointer causing undefined behavior, possibly crash.  Given that simple 3 line program does this havoc, hopefully it makes the point that this is not as trivial or intuitive as you thought it would be.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury - Your `withinHeap` function seems wrong.  Indices in `vector` start from 0 and go to `n-1` where `n` is the number of entries in the vector.  Your function suggests that `n` is a valid index, when it isn't

Comment: @SohamChowdhury - In addition to that, your `display` function goes into an infinite recursive loop.  Your problem is due to stack overflow (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

Given all the comments on the code in terms of C++ techniques (which are all valid), the issue seems to be that your `display` function is causing a stack overflow.

You can see it clearly if you replace the calls to `left()` with what `left()` actually does:

```
void display(int current, int indent)
{
    if (withinHeap(2 * current)) 
        display(2 * current, indent + 4);
    //...
}
```

If we call `display(0, 0);` there is no way that function will return, since you're calling `display` with the same parameter values in a loop.

The `withinHeap` doesn't do anything except check if the parameter is within bounds, and doesn't change the `Heap` object in any way.  Since `0` is within bounds, the call to `withinHeap` always returns `true`.  So it is a given that you're in trouble right from the start of this function.

I won't go into how to fix this, since this is an algorithm issue, not a C++ issue.  However what I pointed out is where your code is causing the error.